# Dropbox image uploads results authentication error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dropbox

I am developing an iphone application which uploads an image to dropbox. I used the following code for image uploading.

```
NSData *datobj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pic.image);
    NSString *stringConvertion = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:datobj encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *filename = stringConvertion;
    NSString *tmpPngFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Temp.png"];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(pic.image) writeToFile:tmpPngFile atomically:NO];
    NSString *destDir = @"/";
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:tmpPngFile];
```

But i am getting an error as follows
error making request to /1/files_put/dropbox - Authentication failed
How can I make authentication ?

Comment: Have you linked with dropbox successfully ?

Comment: Yes...I have successfully integrated dropbox-sdk. I have created an app in the dropbox and i got a key and secret. I added that in the AppDelegate - DBSession* dbSession =
    [[DBSession alloc]
     initWithAppKey:@"mk6v5d6nb4agua6"
     appSecret:@"k7sb0hengqlog9e"
     root:kDBRootDropbox];
    [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];

Comment: For testing, In the uploadFile method can you check with passing just temporaray file name like [[self restClient] uploadFile:@"Temp.png" toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:tmpPngFile];

Comment: I tested using a temp image file, but again the same problem exist...

Comment: @VishnuKumar.S Did you solve your problem using the accepted answer? Because i am getting the same error, but the solution in the accepted answer is already there in my code

Comment: @neeraj : Yes. Add these codes to the plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in the info.plist, below the first  tag

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>db-dz0h38qnvcwrzhk</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```